# Is tachi disrespectful?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, plural-suffixes

If there are only two people concerned but you say for example " John tachi ga" does it imply the other person is less important? Shouldn't it be used for a larger group of people?

Comment: 'tachi' here is like 'et al' ?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93576/45489

Answer (score 3):

If you know both of the two, then yes, somewhat. It's better to include both and say ジョンと太郎 for example. Leaving one out invites the question why, it can be taken as intentionally excluding that person. However, depending on the situation, it can be reasonably explained otherwise and not taken as disrespectful. If you know the name of only one of the two (and that is John), then ジョンたち might be more acceptable. If John is the only shared friend of you and the listener, it can be natural to focus on him by saying ジョンたち.

Answer (score 3):

If there are two or fewer people you are considering, you should probably say their names, but if there are three or more, it is difficult to say everyone's name, so you can call them "〇〇たち"

It's not that the word is that impolite." You guys are" and "〇〇 and the others" have the same meaning.